# NHibernate query for most recent records

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

Ok, this should be really simple.  I'm new to NHibernate, but everywhere I've searched has given me conflicting answers on this, and none of them seem to work.  Basically, I need to implement the following SQL query into my code.  It simply returns the most recent records for a specific participant.

```
select *
from result
where ParticipantId = 1
and ResultDate = (select MAX(resultDate)
                  from Result
                  where ParticipantId = 1)
```

I'm using Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate 3.3.  I can pull back the data without the "and" in the where clause using the code below, but when I try to restrict it to the most recent records, nothing's working.

```
var resultSet = session.Query<Result>()
.Where(r => r.Participant.ParticipantId == 1);
```

Also including my domain and mapping files here for completeness.  Let me know if more info is needed.

```
public class Result
{
    public virtual int ResultId { get; set; }
    public virtual Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public virtual ResultType ResultType { get; set; }
    public virtual float? ResultValue { get; set; }
    public virtual string ResultText { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ResultDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Systolic { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Diastolic { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChangedBy { get; set; }
}

public ResultMap() 
{
    Table("Result");
    LazyLoad();
    Id(x => x.ResultId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ResultId");
    References(x => x.Participant).Column("ParticipantId");
    References(x => x.ResultType).Column("ResultTypeId");
    Map(x => x.ResultValue).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.ResultText).Nullable().Length(100);
    Map(x => x.ResultDate).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Systolic).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Diastolic).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.DateAdded).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.AddedBy).Nullable().Length(100);
    Map(x => x.DateChanged).Nullable();
    Map(x => x.ChangedBy).Nullable().Length(100);
}
```

Any thoughts on an easy solution to get the recent data?  Bonus points for letting me know how to get the last 2 dates, as I'll need them soon for comparing improvements.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get that same query via QueryOver...

```
var maxResultDate = QueryOver.Of<Result>()
    .Where(x => x.Participant.ParticipantId  == 1)
    .Select(Projections.Max<Result>(x => x.ResultDate));

var rslt = s.QueryOver<Result>()
    .Where(x => x.Participant.ParticipantId == 1)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.ResultDate).Eq(maxResultDate)
      //or to get the "last" 2 rows...
      //.OrderBy(x => x.ResultDate).Desc
      //.Take(2)
    .List();
```